Facing DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error with the @google-cloud/pubsub package
We are listening for messages from a subscription using the @google-cloud/pubsub package. Everything seems to be working fine, except we are seeing an error frequently pop up in our DataDog console:
Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded after 900.000s,LB pick: 0.001s,remote_addr=172.253.122.95:443
    at callErrorFromStatus (/app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/call.ts:82:17)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:706:51)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client-interceptors.ts:419:48)
    at /app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/resolving-call.ts:163:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
for call at
    at ServiceClientImpl.makeBidiStreamRequest (/app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/client.ts:690:42)
    at ServiceClientImpl.<anonymous> (/app/backend/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/src/make-client.ts:189:15)
    at /dd_tracer/node/dd-trace/packages/datadog-instrumentations/src/grpc/client.js:168:27
    at run (/dd_tracer/node/dc-polyfill/patch-channel-store-methods.js:39:16)
    at AsyncResourceStorage.run (/dd_tracer/node/dd-trace/packages/datadog-core/src/storage/async_resource.js:69:14)
    at /dd_tracer/node/dc-polyfill/patch-channel-store-methods.js:70:18
    at Channel.ch.runStores (/dd_tracer/node/dc-polyfill/patch-channel-store-methods.js:48:14)
    at callMethod (/dd_tracer/node/dd-trace/packages/datadog-instrumentations/src/grpc/client.js:158:23)
    at ServiceClientImpl.wrapped [as streamingPull] (/dd_tracer/node/dd-trace/packages/datadog-instrumentations/src/grpc/client.js:93:12)
    at MessageStream._fillOne (/app/backend/node_modules/@google-cloud/pubsub/src/message-stream.ts:332:39)

With this call stack, we are not able to debug anything. Below is how we are listening for messages:
const pubsubClient = new PubSub();

const subscription = pubsubClient.subscription(
  '<subscription-name>',
  {
     flowControl: {
        maxMessages: 100,
     },
  },
);

subscription.on('message', async (msg) => {
    try {
        // Process the message...

        msg.ack();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error in pub/sub', error);
        msg.nack();
    }
});

subscription.on('error', (err) =>
    console.error('Error in pub/sub', err),
);

Since the functionality is working fine, this error isn't urgent, but we would like this error to go away. There is some discussion in this issue but no solution yet.
I tried to inspect the call stack but that led to nothing. I looked at existing discussions online, but no solution yet.

The timeout appears to be hardcoded in [@google-cloud/pubsub] as StreamingPull.timeout_millis. You say that the "functionality is working fine", do I understand from this that the client reconnects or otherwise continues after the error?

I don't know, but we don't seem to miss any messages. That maybe also because we have multiple instances of the subscriber running.
